# Can I visit zurich with my business short stay schengen visa?

Tags: switzerland, zurich, schengen-visas

i am attending an interview and they want me to apply for business short stay schengen visa.i am planning to visit zurich as my friend is there. So, after interview i am planning to go to zurich, stay there for 2 days, return back to amsterdam and fly back to india. Is this possible with this visa?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this ought to be okay. The interview is plainly still the *main purpose* of your visit to the Schengen area, and visiting a friend is incidental to this purpose. So you should apply to a visa from the Netherlands -- once you're in, there will be nothing stopping you from making the side trip to Switzerland.

Comment: Make sure that both Amsterdam and Zurich are on your itinerary.